# Spreadsheet Style Control (iOS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need a control that closely represents the style of a Spreadsheet in a iOS application I am writing.

Would the **UICollectionView** provide this appearance?

All I need to do is display data so there would be no editing of the data needed.

Fritzables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe need a UIScrollView where you manage the "Cells" yourself.

Collection views are useful if you need your content to "flow" in some way which I think is not the case here.

You might consider a table view which includes vertical scrolling and row editing etc. but you still have to deal with horizontal offscreen content yourself.

With UIScrollView you have full flexibility to lay out your cells (like tiles) as desired in a fixed way. Panning and zooming is included for free.

Comment: I have decided to put a UITableView in place with a custom Cell which will house labels to represent the columns I need displaying.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for something similar a couple of months ago. Ended up writing my own set of classes.

There were a few projects that I checked out on github, see if they are of any use -

https://github.com/macmoe/JDMTableGridView

https://github.com/yuch/GridTable